# Add custom image size not working

Tags: functions, images

I want to add a custom image size to my child theme.

The base is the Penscratch theme, and it has it own image sizes defined:

```
function penscratch_setup() {

    /*  ...  */

    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size( 'penscratch-featured', '400', '200', true );

    /*  ...  */
}
```

And if I made some changes here (base functions.php), everything work as it should, But the point is to make it done in child-Theme, I'm writing it the same way but for some reason it's not working:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_teme', 'add_custom_img_sizes');

function add_custom_img_sizes()
{    
  add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
  add_image_size( 'category-thumbnail', '300', '200', true );
}
```

if I use then the 'category-thumbnail' in my template, it is displaying the full-sized image, not the cropped one, what is going wrong here?

Comment: You've misspelled the action name (you're missing the `h` in `theme`). You may also need to select the desired image size where you display the image in your template - normally you'd use something like [`the_post_thumbnail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/) to do so, however the "category-thumbnail" you mention isn't a part of WordPress core. You may need to address your question to the respective theme or plugin author.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you add a new image size, you have to regenerate the images for that size. The [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin comes in handy for this purpose.

Comment: But when I'm making the changes to the base theme functions.php (penscratch theme), it's all working with just the page reload. So I guess it's not about some external plugin.

Comment: That's only possible if A) the base theme has the exact image size declaration "name" B) That image declaration declares the same "size" 3) the image physically exists of that size.

penscratch-featured already existed when the image was uploaded. Durign the upload the image was resized to '400' x '200' and that image physically exists on the server. After you change the name or the size you'll need to reupload the image so that the new image size is regenerated or use the plugin to achieve it.

Comment: You're right, I was making the changes on an existing entry. Thanks for making this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the Command Line Interface (CLI) to regenerate the thumbnails using the [wp media regenerate](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/regenerate/) command:

```
wp media regenerate
```

Have a look at [this page](https://make.wordpress.org/cli/handbook/installing/) and follow the steps to install the **wp** command.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the handle name in your the post thumbnail

```
 the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumbnail' );
```

Comment: I wrote in my post, that I did this already. The last sentence of my question.